# Calculating the force between a collision of unequal masses and unequal velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, simulations

I'm writing a physics engine, and it works by implementing forces. Inside the world, you can add a constant force to any object (the most obvious of which would be gravity), and you can add a temporary force to each object-- one that will be implemented once during the next time step. The objects each contain a mass, velocity, acceleration, a bounding box, a net force, and a container holding the constant forces to be applied at each time step. Obviously if you wanted to apply the constant force of gravity to a 100 gram object, then you would need to multiply 9.8, or whatever the gravity is, by 100 grams. So the constant force you would add is 980 N. I have a system that can detect when a collision happens, but I need to know what the force is applied to each of the two or more objects colliding. I realize that it is "equal and opposite," but I can't find anything explaining how to calculate that force. Not only does this equation need to handle an object colliding with another object at rest, but it also needs to handle an object hitting another object that's not at rest. These objects do not necessarily have the same mass or the same velocity. Friction is not yet implemented, so the collisions are perfectly elastic. Another thing to consider is that some objects in the simulation may have infinite mass, and have no constant forces acting on them. If a normal object collides with this object of infinite mass, then I need the equation to function as it would any other object, applying an equal force to both of the objects in the system. Of course, the object of infinite mass would not gain any acceleration from this, naturally meaning it cannot move. (force/Infinity=0). The information I have readily available is as follows: force, acceleration, velocity, mass, and position. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite mass is tricky since it implies infinite momentum, so therefore the conservation of momentum doesn't really make sense since $\infty + 1 = \infty$, so you have to decide how you would like to deal with that, and obviously there is the classic paradox of the collision of two infinite masses which is often written as "what happens when an immovable object meets an unstoppable force", so be weary of infinite masses since they tend to 'break' physics (rightfully so since infinite mass isn't a real thing).

As for the collisions, you really have to try and come up with a way of analyzing the elasticity of the collision to find the resulting velocities; this is no easy task and includes analyzing the materials that are colliding (are they compressible, and how much), the energy lost to sound, friction, heat, etc. And of course how long the collision lasts.

It sounds however that you are developing a very simple Physics Engine, which is fine, and if we are to assume fully elastic collisions, then the resulting velocities $v_1, v_2$ from the initial velocities $u_1, u_2$ of two masses $m_1, m_2$ respectively is given as follows:

\begin{array}{ccc}v_{1}&=&\displaystyle {\frac {m_{1}-m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{1}+{\frac {2m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{2}\\[.5em]v_{2}&=&\displaystyle {\frac {2m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{1}+{\frac {m_{2}-m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{2}\end{array}

That is all you need to analyze the motion of the objects, but if you are really interested in the Force of the collision, then you need to identify a time $\Delta t$ over which the collision takes place, and the force of collision is then $F=\frac{m_1(v_1-u_1)}{\Delta t}=\frac{m_2(v_2-u_2)}{\Delta t}$. This is impulse, which is what connects applied force to collisions. Of course this assumes that the force $F$ is constant over $\Delta t$. If you would like to assume a Gaussian distribution of force w.r.t time, or a triangle or whatever, then you would obtain a corresponding $F(t)$, which is easy enough to solve. Physics Engines can be as complicated or simple as you wish.

Comment: thank you! that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: The force curve for the simplest of elastic contact models is actually not a Gaussian distribution, but the top half of a cosine curve.